# Is it possible for a key to have multiple names in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm not sure if this is even possible but it's worth a shot asking.

I want to be able to access the value from indexing one of the values.

The first thing that came to mind was this but of course, it didn't work.

```
dict = {['name1', 'name2'] : 'value1'}
print(dict.get('name1))
```

Comment: do you mind how the keys are stored inside the dictionary?

Comment: David S no i dont mind, as long as i can access them. It's all going to be stored in a static variable either way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a tuple (as it's immutable) as a dict key if you need to access it by a pair (or more) of strings (or other immutable values):

```
>>> d = {}
>>> d[("foo", "bar")] = 6
>>> d[("foo", "baz")] = 8
>>> d
{('foo', 'bar'): 6, ('foo', 'baz'): 8}
>>> d[("foo", "baz")]
8
>>>
```

This isn't "a key having multiple names", though, it's just a key that happens to be built of multiple strings.

### Edit

As discussed in the comments, the end goal is to have multiple keys for each (static) value.  That can be succinctly accomplished with an inverted dict first, which is then "flipped" using `dict.fromkeys()`:

```
def foobar():
    pass

def spameggs():
    pass

func_to_names = {
  foobar: ("foo", "bar", "fb", "foobar"),
  spameggs: ("spam", "eggs", "se", "breakfast"),
}
name_to_func = {}
for func, names in func_to_names.items():
    name_to_func.update(dict.fromkeys(names, func))
```

Comment: Sorry i didn't specify this in the question. I want to be able to access the value by indexing one of the key names from the array.

Comment: Do you mean you'd want to access the same value using multiple different keys? Why? What's your actual use-case?

Comment: AKX I have a file full of functions and i need to access them from user input, i thought that sorting through a dictonary would be much more efficient than a list of if else statements

Comment: Right, it will be. But in that case just assign the same function into the dict with as many separate names as you need.

Comment: So something like  `dict = {"foobar":foo(), "foobaz":foo(), "barfoo":bar(), "barbaz":bar()}`? I was going to do that initially but i thought if i could just put all of them in an array it would be quicker to make and i'd learn something new

Comment: Wow! Thanks! This is a really smart solution.

Answer (score 0):

If we tried it you way using:

```python
# Creating a dictionary 
myDict = {[1, 2]: 'Names'} 

print(myDict)
```

We get an output of:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

To get around this, we can use this method:

```python
# Creating an empty dictionary 
myDict = {} 

# Adding list as value 
myDict["key1"] = [1, 2] 
myDict["key2"] = ["Jim", "Jeff", "Jack"] 

print(myDict)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But in the question I want the keys to have multiple names, not the values.